# Finding modes for multiple dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key, mode

I currently have a Python dictionary with keys assigned to multiple values (which have come from a CSV), in a format similar to:

```
{
'hours': ['4', '2.4', '5.8', '2.4', '7'],
'name': ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Adam', 'John', 'Harry'],
'salary': ['55000', '30000', '55000', '30000', '80000']
}
```

(The actual dictionary is significantly larger in both keys and values.)

I am looking to find the mode* for each set of values, with the stipulation that sets where all values occur only once do not need a mode. However, I'm not sure how to go about this (and I can't find any other examples similar to this). I am also concerned about the different (implied) data types for each set of values (e.g. 'hours' values are floats, 'name' values are strings, 'salary' values are integers), though I have a rudimentary conversion function included but not used yet.

```
import csv

f = 'blah.csv'

# Conducts type conversion
def conversion(value):
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return value

reader = csv.DictReader(open(f))

# Places csv into a dictionary
csv_dict = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
        csv_dict.setdefault(column, []).append(value.strip())
```

*I'm wanting to attempt other types of calculations as well, such as averages and quartiles- which is why I'm concerned about data types- but I'd mostly like assistance with modes for now.

EDIT: the input CSV file can change; I'm unsure if this has any effect on potential solutions.

Comment: Mode is ambiguous, do you want *all* modes or just *any* mode? For example if there are multiple items with the same # of repetitions which is the max # of repetitions, do you want to return them all? or just any one? or none?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I believe my answer would be 'all of them'. The example I have, would return 2.4 for hours, Adam for name, and, 55000 and 30000 for salary. DId I understand your question right?

Comment: No I meant for a single key. For example if hours was [4,4,4,6,6,6] should you return 4, or [4,6] as the mode?

Comment: For a single key, it should return [4,6]- but only if they occur more than once. If hours itself was [4,6], it should return nothing; [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] would also return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring all the csv file stuff which seems tangential to your question, lets say you have a list `salary`.  You can use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from `collections` to count the unique list elements.

From that you have a number of different options about how to get from a `Counter` to your mode.

For example:

```
from collections import Counter

salary = ['55000', '30000', '55000', '30000', '80000']

counter = Counter(salary)

# This returns all unique list elements and their count, sorted by count, descending
mc = counter.most_common()
print(mc)

# This returns the unique list elements and their count, where their count equals
#   the count of the most common list element.
gmc = [(k,c) for (k,c) in mc if c == mc[0][1]]
print(gmc)

# If you just want an arbitrary (list element, count) pair that has the most occurences
amc = counter.most_common()[0]
print(amc)
```

For the `salary` list in the code, this outputs:

```
[('55000', 2), ('30000', 2), ('80000', 1)]  # mc
[('55000', 2), ('30000', 2)]                # gmc
('55000', 2)                                # amc
```

Of course, for your case you'd probably use `Counter(csv_dict["salary"])` instead of `Counter(salary)`.

Comment: It's occurred to me that I didn't specify whether the possible input CSV changes- it can. Does that change your answer? Should I perhaps iterate through column headings in some way where you have written `counter = Counter(salary)` (where `salary` would change)?

Comment: @Auhsoj100 yeah, thats what I was suggesting at the very end of my answer, that you might want something like `Counter(csv_dict["salary"])` instead of `Counter(salary)`

Comment: I'm under the impression though that I can't hard-code `Counter(csv_dict["salary"])` because the CSV input can change (and so the keys/CSV headings, e.g. 'salary' can as well). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Auhsoj100 No, you're not.  If the headings can change too you'd want to pass the heading into the `csv_dict` as a variable (e.g. `Counter(csv_dict[some_header])`).  Maybe loop through the possible headers like: `for some_header in all_headers: Counter(csv_dict[some_header])`

Comment: Ok, this seems like a good possible route. I'll see how I go, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you could create a dictionary matching each desired mode to those keys, manually, or you could use the 'type' class by asking the values, then if the type returns a string ask other questions/parameters, like length of the item.